# Session handling with RavenDB and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I have a service class UserService that gets an instance of IDocumentStore injected using AutoFac. This is working fine but now I'm looking at code like this:

```
public void Create(User user)
{
    using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Store(user);
        session.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Every action that writes to the db uses this same structure:

```
using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
{
    dosomething...
    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

What is the best way to eliminate this repetitive code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is implementing `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` on a base controller and use it.

let's imagine you create your `RavenController` like this:

```
public class RavenController : Controller
{
    public IDocumentSession Session { get; set; }
    protected IDocumentStore _documentStore;

    public RavenController(IDocumentStore documentStore)
    {
        _documentStore = documentStore;
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Session = _documentStore.OpenSession();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        using (Session)
        {
            if (Session != null && filterContext.Exception == null)
            {
                Session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

then all you need to do in your own controllers is inherit from `RavenController` like this:

```
public class HomeController : RavenController
{
    public HomeController(IDocumentStore store)
        : base(store)
    {

    }

    public ActionResult CreateUser(UserModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            User user = Session.Load<User>(model.email);
            if (user == null) { 
                // no user found, let's create it
                Session.Store(model);
            }
            else {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "That email already exists.");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

---

**Interesting enough**, I have found a blog post showing exactly this technique ...

it does explain way more that what I did. I hope it helps you better

> [Building an ASP.NET MVC app using RavenDB as a Backing Store](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=787)

Comment: I have read similar instructions (somewhere in the ravendb tutorials) but I wanted to move this kind of logic into my services layer as I thought this shouldn't be part of my controllers.

Comment: then implement it in your DLL, the same way. I use it on my Repository layer but I always use a Cache Layer before.

Comment: how would I do that? In my service classes I do not have ActionExecuting and ActionEcecuted available.

Comment: sure you don't, but you can inherit your service class from `IDisposable` and dispose the session there, on your view controller, you keep using the same base controller for all controllers that need access to your database, but disposing or call a disposable method on your repository layer.

Comment: @balexandre How do you handle ConcurrencyException? What do you show to user when this exception throw? It is going more interesting when you use PRG pattern, what then?

Comment: @dario There are several `ConcurrencyException` tutorials out there, this question was about Session Handling...

Comment: @balexandre I saw those tutorials but your solution (which is fine IMHO for Web Api) doesn't give any possibility to show any nice and concrete explanation what just happened when concurrency exception occurs. I'm looking for session management which can give possibility to populate ModelState (especially for PRG pattern where on error redirects to previous action which can be different from redirecting after positive action).

Comment: One of the best solutions I have found if to use messaging (f.ex. [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)) and once you you have an update, just propagate a message to all connected subscribers that a change on that *Product* was made since they reload the page, then: *Please click here to reload the new values*